# spacing between table for html emails

Tags: html, html-email

I am constructing a **HTML email** newsletter.

Within the email, i constructed a **container table** that will hold the actual content of the email; configured to 100% width.

i then built other tables, within the **"outer container table"** to hold different part of the message; these table are aligned next to each other/and below each other.

**The issue**

the issue is how to space the inner tables. i tried the standard inline **css margin-left/padding-left spacing**. but none seem to have an affect.

```
style=' margin-right: 20px;float: left;margin-bottom: 20px'
```

below is the sample table. please note that this example is contained within a properly formatted header and foooter(i did not show that part for brevity).

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width='300' style='float:left' style=' margin-right: 20px;float: left;margin-bottom: 20px'>
       <TABLE>
         <TR>
            <TD width='150'>column</TD> 
         </TR>
      </TABLE>
    </td>
   <td width='300' style='float:left' style=' margin-right: 20px;float: left;margin-bottom: 20px'>
      <TABLE>
        <TR>
          <TD width='150'>column</TD> 
        </TR>
      </TABLE>
   </td>       

  <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `style` tag twice in your code. Just remove that and inner CSS will work.

Try this

```
<table width="100%" style='border:1px solid green;'>
  <tr>
    <td width='300' style='border:1px solid blue; margin-right: 20px;float: left; margin-bottom: 20px'>
       <TABLE>
         <TR>
            <TD style='border:1px solid red;' width='150'>column</TD> 
         </TR>
      </TABLE>
    </td>
   <td width='300' style='border:1px solid red;margin-right: 20px; float: left; margin-bottom: 30px'>
     <TABLE>
        <TR>
          <TD width='150'>column</TD> 
        </TR>
      </TABLE>
   </td>    
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: All the best @Paul Kendal.  :)